# How effective is it to rinse fruit, lettuce, tomato, ... with water?

Tags: health, fruit, vegetable, hygiene

The general rule I've seen stated is that to get rid of some nasty bacteria, one should rinse fruit and vegetable under running water before using them, especially if eaten raw.

Most likely the effectiveness of such a measure depends significantly on the details of how this rinsing happens.  So, by how much is the risk of health problems reduced in different cases (e.g. just bath the fruit&vegetable in a water bowl, pass them quickly under running water, bath them and scrub them, keep them for a minute under running water (moving them around and scrubbing them at the same time), ...).

Of course, assuming those fruit&vegetable have already been washed earlier (e.g. before we bought them).

Comment: I suggest reading [this FDA page](https://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm114299). See "Prepare Safely".

Comment: @Charles: This page is the kind of example I mention that gives general rules, but without detailing the actual effect on the probability of getting ill, nor discussing how that probability is affected by the various rules they propose and how we choose to follow them.

Comment: I **strongly** doubt that studies have been conducted which test the rates of individuals falling ill from food-borne bacteria with respect to varying degrees of wash for fruit & vegetables. I *do* however believe though that there were initial studies which established how long a fruit/vegetable should be washed, as to sufficiently remove pesticides, bacteria, and any other undesired substance(s).

Comment: @Charles: Could you give me some pointers to those studies?